# Vue.js - How to forbid to generate the __vue__ property when insert one element into DOM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue2 (2.6.11), and recently our customers raised some CSP issues. In order to resolve these issues, I setup a response header in my `webpack-dev-server` with below config:

```
headers: {
 'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only': "script-src 'self'"
}
```

now when access the app, I already found below errors output in console:

```
[Report Only] Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

By checking the codes, I found it was caused by below codes in vue.rumtime.esm.js:

```
function insertBefore (parentNode, newNode, referenceNode) {
  parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);
}
```

And the reason why to report the error here, is for the newNode contains a `__vue__` property, and the content of `__vue__` is the vue instance object. So execute the insertBefore function will trigger the error since it will be handled as inline scripts. By searching online, it seems the `__vue__` property mainly used to make the instances discoverable by `vue-devtools`. But I really don't want to leaks this property in the DOM since it violates the CSP rule. Does anybody know how to forbid to generate this property when using vue2 ?

Comment: Did you try the PRODUCTION BUILD? `__vue__` sounds like a dev-mode thing

Comment: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments